# How to clean a tox environment after running?

Tags: python, tox

I have the following `tox.ini` file:

```
[tox]
envlist = flake8,py{35,36,37,38}{,-keyring}

[testenv]
usedevelop = True
install_command = pip install -U {opts} {packages}
deps =
    .[test]
    keyring: .[keyring]
setenv =
    COVERAGE_FILE = .coverage.{envname}
commands=
    pytest {toxinidir}/tests -n 4 {posargs}

[testenv:flake8]
basepython = python3
deps = flake8
commands=
    flake8 src tests

[flake8]
ignore: F401,E402,E501,W605,W503
```

When I run the `tox` command, it creates a `.tox` folder containing a folder for every environment specified in the `[tox]` section of the `tox.ini`.

I would like to automatically get rid of these particular folders after the test have succeeded when running `tox` without having to manually run `rm -rf .tox/NAME_OF_THE_ENV`. I have searched through the tox documentation but I have found nothing.

Is it possible to do so? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way by creating a tox hook. This hook runs the `shutil.rmtree` command after the tests have been run inside the env.

In a `tox_clean_env.py` file:

```
import shutil
from tox import hookimpl

@hookimpl
def tox_runtest_post(venv):
    try:
        shutil.rmtree(venv.path)
    except Exception as e:
        print("An exception occurred while removing '{}':".format(venv.path))
        print(e)
```

I created a package around this code and I just need to install it using `pip`.

In my `setup.py`, in the `setup` function:

```
    entry_points={"tox": ["clean_env = tox_clean_env"]},
```

Answer (score 23):

I know it's not exactly what you were asking for but it's worth mentioning that the `-r / --recreate` flag to tox will [force recreation of virtual environments](https://tox.wiki/en/latest/cli_interface.html#tox---recreate)

Answer (score 10):

There is no way in `tox`. The reason is that `tox` preserves these environments as a cache: next time you run `tox` the environments will be reused thus saving time.

You can remove them at once after running `tox` with `rm -rf .tox`.

Answer (score 2):

The new version **tox 3.18** (July 23, 2020) has a setting `allowlist_externals=(MULTI-LINE-LIST)` that allows to specify command names which can be used in the commands section without triggering a “not installed in virtualenv” warning. That allows to use `rm` command directly.

```
[testenv]
...
allowlist_externals = rm
commands=
    pytest ...
    rm -rf {envdir}
```

The line with `rm` command is not executed after errors. (unless you add a setting `ignore_errors = True` that allows to continue)